# Best way to execute a function inside another, repeatedly used function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am creating a web interface for an application on an ESP8266 where I send certain data to the Interface via AJAX and Javascript. The data gets send every second at the moment. Since this takes a moment upon first loading of the page, I want to make it visible only after the information arrived. Right now I got the following, working solution:

```
<body onload="doAjax()">
<div id="interface-content" style="display: none">
Some content
</div>
</body>

<script>
function doAjax(action = "getCont", callback = continousStuff) {

        var ajaxRequest = null;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
        else { ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }

        if (!ajaxRequest) { alert("AJAX is not supported."); return; }

        ajaxRequest.open("GET", action, true);

        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {


                callback(ajaxRequest.responseText);
                //Here I make the content visible:
                document.getElementById("interface-content").style.display = "block";
            }
        }
        ajaxRequest.send();            
    }
    var a = setInterval('doAjax("getCont", continousStuff)', 1000);
</script>
```

Now the `display="block"`gets executed every second too. I am wondering, is there a better way to just have this line executed only once, after the data is received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check whether or not your div's display property is 'block' and if not, change it to block. this way, it will change it only once.

```
let element =  document.getElementById("interface-content");
if(element.style.display !== "block") {
    element.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know what kind of difference this makes in terms of perfomance? I mean it's already not a problem, but I would like to get as close as it gets to an optimal solution.

Comment: Since it's just a comparaison, it won't have any major impact. You could improve it by moving the `let element =  document.getElementById("interface-content");` outside of your success callback, so the DOM won't be parse every seconds, then you could set a flag if you already changed it and then validate that the flag is true, so you wouldn't have to retrieve the style of the object each time. @Nalp

Answer (score 0):

When your request takes longer than a second, you may have the function running twice interacting badly with each other. Also, when having multiple users on your site, a request per second may become quite heavy. It may be better if the function rescheduled itself, something like

```js
function doAjax(action = "getCont", callback = continousStuff)
{
  //... prepare the request
  ajaxRequest.open("GET", action, false);

  //... evaluate the result

  // reschedule
  setTimeout(doAjax, 1000, action, callback);
}

// run the function initially
setTimeout(doAjax, 0, "getCont", continousStuff);
```

This may work better as it only reschedules the function once the previous run has finished. It also uses `async = false` so the call wouldn't return before it finished.

Additionally, you could add a random value to the reschedule timeout to spread out multiple users more evenly.

The ultimate solution, tho, may be to use web channels (pubsub, ...) to push an update from the server to the client which only does the Ajax call when the push notification was sent.

PS: You should not pass the function as a string to not fight with any escaping that might be need. Use one of these:

```js
setTimeout(
  (function() {
    callYourFunctionHere(param1, param2);
    // and do some stuff
  }),
  1000
);

// OR

// note the missing () to pass it as a function param instead of running it
setTimeout(callYourFunctionHere, 1000, param1, param2);
```